# Name for optimally mixing a population

Tags: combinatorics

I'm at a loss as to what terms I should be searching for in order to learn more about the work already done addressing this task: take a population and arrange it according to one or more properties so that it is well-mixed. For example, if you start with a population described by IDs, Letters, and Gender, that looks like this:

```
ID  Letter  Gender  LD  GD  LD^2 GD^2
1   Alpha   Male      1   1   1    1
2   Alpha   Male      1   3   1    9
3   Alpha   Female    1   1   1    1
4   Alpha   Female    5   4  25   16
5   Beta    Male      1   1   1    1
6   Beta    Male      7   1  49    1
7   Gamma   Male      8   2  64    4
8   Delta   Female    8   3  64    9
SUM OF SQUARES:             206   42
```

I would like to order the elements according to Letter and Gender to look like this:

```
ID  Letter  Gender  LD  GD  LD^2 GD^2
1   Alpha   Male      2   1   4    1
5   Beta    Male      4   2  16    4
3   Alpha   Female    2   2   4    4
7   Gamma   Male      8   2  64    4
4   Alpha   Female    2   3   4    9
6   Beta    Male      4   1  16    1
2   Alpha   Male      2   2   4    4
8   Delta   Female    8   3  64    9
SUM OF SQUARES:             176   36
```

The idea is to have any consecutive group of elements be as representative of the whole as possible. My `LD` and `GD` columns list the distance to the next element that has the same Letter (for `LD`) or Gender (for `GD`), looping back around to the beginning and possibly finding itself, if it is a unique value. The sum of those columns will be the same regardless of how you order them, so I calculate the squares of those values. I want the sum of the squared values to be as low as possible in an optimal mix.

This seems like it falls under combinatorics, but from that point, I'm at a loss. What is the name of this sort of operation? I'm not looking to count the number of possible orderings, but rather to find one of the optimal orderings to meet my need.

I have to imagine that others have looked into this sort of thing before and that they have terminology for it that I simply don't know about.

Perhaps this is a better way of putting it: I want to order the population so that the composition of every possible set of contiguous elements is as close to representative of the whole as possible. That is, if 25% of the elements in the population have "Beta" as their Letter value, then every contiguous set of 4 elements should have 1 and only 1 "Beta."

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this isn't oversimplifying, but this sounds like a [shuffle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shuffle.html). If you replace "letter" with "number" and "gender" with "suit", you have the particular case of a deck of cards.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds close. I'm not looking to create a random ordering, however. An "optimally mixed" deck of cards would go club, diamond, heart, spade, club, diamond heart, spade, club... etc. And the values would presumably go something like ace, king, two, queen, three, jack, four, ten, five, nine, six, eight, seven, ace, king... etc.

Comment: Your "optimal mixing" works nicely for the deck of cards since you can choose a pattern and repeat it. In general, though (and in the example you wrote) no such repeating pattern will be possible. Perhaps you can try to further formalize what "optimal mixing" means?